# .htaccess rewrite php to php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am currently trying to write a rewrite rule. I want to simplify the entered URL so that it will always use the index. The input url would be `www.example.com/home.php` and would be rewritten to `www.example.com/index.php?r=page/home`.

I wrote this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?r=page/$1 [L]
```

This configuration unfortunately gives me an error 500. I can understand that it is caused by the fact that if I enter `index.php` for instance, apache will not know if it must use the `index.php` file or use the rewritten url `index.php?r=page/index`.

Is it possible to accomplish this kind of rewriting rule with apache? If so, how can I fix my error 500?

**Edit:** Please note that the RewriteRule works fine if I change the extension `.php` to anything else such as `.html`, as so: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?r=page/$1 [L]`

Comment: Error 500 doesn't mean your RewriteRule is wrong or points toward a page it does not exist. It means you have an error in the syntax of your file (I don't see any) or your configuration. Is there anything else in your .htaccess file ? Does mod_rewrite is correctly installed ?

Comment: I tried changing the rewriting rule to that: "RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.pr$ /index.php?r=page/$1 [L]" and it worked when I try to access www.domain.com/home.pr... So it is the ".php" that cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

First one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ /index.php?r=page/$1 [L]
```

Second one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^/]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?r=page/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I used the first one, how exactly does it work? What does the dash means?

Comment: The first one does nothing if `index.php` is requested (the dash means `do nothing`). The second one uses `THE_REQUEST`: this way you can make difference between internal redirect and original request. Both are equivalent in this case

Answer (score 1):

you can also try with this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=page/$1 [L]
```