# Remove '.php' file extension but still validate paramaters after trailing slash?

Tags: php, .htaccess, trailing-slash

I've been searching for how to do this, and I haven't been able to get anything to work yet. I want to remove the '.php' file extension from all files that have it while also adding a trailing slash and validating all the parameters following it. For example, I want `my/directory/users/USER_ID/` to function the same as `my/directory/users.php/USER_ID/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite php to php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951819/htaccess-rewrite-php-to-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

As you reference Apache, here's one way of doing it in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my/directory/users/([0-9]+)/$ my/directory/users.php/$1/ [L]
```

- Look for incoming URLs which match the regex `^my/directory/users/([0-9]+)/$`.

  - `^` means 'start of the url'
  - `$` means 'end of the url'
  - `[0-9]+` means 'at least one digit here'
  - The brackets tell it to capture that digit series as a variable. It's the only variable we create, so it'll end up as `$1`.
- If we match on that URL, we'll rewrite it to `my/directory/users.php/$1/` and then stop considering any other rewrite rules, because this is a [L]ast one.

  - Using the variable `$1`, the previously captured digit series.

Comment: Thank you for this concise answer, I also want to remove the ```.php``` file extension from any URL on my page that has it and I was able to achieve that but when attempting to use a trailing slash and parameters with those rules, those pages are seen as directories. For example, ```my/directory/users```  would work but ```my/directory/users/1``` would not.